# iOS send message to Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to refresh flutter when I click iOS `UITabbarItem`. What should I do?

Can you give me an example?

```
- (void)setupSubFlutterNav {

    _vc1 = [[FlutterViewController alloc] init];
    [_vc1 setInitialRoute:@"/route"];
    _vc1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    _vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_vc2];
    nav2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    _vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_vc3];
    nav3.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    self.viewControllers = @[_vc1, nav2, nav3];
}
```

Comment: Objective-C
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"samples.flutter.io/battery" binaryMessenger:_appointmentController];
    [channel invokeMethod:@"foo" arguments:nil result:^(id  _Nullable result) {
        
    }];
}

Comment: Data
static const _methodChannel = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/battery');

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(_handler);
}

Future<dynamic> _handler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
  switch (methodCall.method) {
    case 'foo':
      // DO REFRESH
    default:
      
  }
}